# R separate words from numbers in string

Tags: r, regex, data-cleaning

I need to clean up some data strings that have words and numbers or just numbers.

below is a toy sample

```
library(tidyverse)

c("555","Word 123", "two words 123", "three words here 123") %>%  
sub("(\\w+) (\\d*)",  "\\1|\\2", .)
```

The result is this:

```
[1] "555"                  "Word|123"             "two|words 123"        "three|words here 123"
```

but I want to place the '|' before the last set of numbers like shown below

```
[1] "|555"                  "Word|123"             "two words|123"        "three words here|123"
```

Comment: Try with `sub("(\\w+ )?(\\d)",  "\\1|\\2", v1)`

Comment: @akrun this works, can you make it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by a digit we capture as a group (`(\\d)`) and in the replacement use the `|` followed by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("\\s*(\\d)", "|\\1", v1)
#[1] "|555"                 "Word|123"            
#[3] "two words|123"        "three words here|123"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("555","Word 123", "two words 123", "three words here 123")
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
^(.*?)\s*(\d*)$
```

Replace with `\1|\2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U0nc2I/1).

[image]

In R:

```
sub("^(.*?)\\s*(\\d*)$", "\\1|\\2", .)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d*)` - Capturing group 2: zero or more digits
- `$` - end of string.