# Separate words from numbers using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, data-cleaning

I have a list of adresses that i need to clean up.

The goal is to add a space before the numbers as shown in below examples.

```
16AVCHARLESDAGAULLECS10525             16 Avcharlesdagaullecs 10525
1BDHIPPOLYTEMARQUES                    1 Bdhippolytemarques
20GARRICKSTREET4THFLOOR                20 Garrickstreet 4Thfloor
2109ZAC                                2109 Zac
2-4VANDRIESSTREET4                     2-4 Vandriesstreet 4
5:ETVÄRG.19.E                          5:Etvärg. 19.E
901ACEHIGHENTTOWE9TH233                901 Acehighenttowe 9Th 233
```

I have found a script that puts spaces in between letters but that is not my goal. Here is the code I have so far. **It does not give the result abowe.**

```
Function Add_Spaces(ByVal sText As String) As String
   Dim CharNum As Long
   Dim FixedText As String
   Dim CharCode As Long

   FixedText = Left(sText, 1)

   For CharNum = 2 To Len(sText)
      CharCode = Asc(Mid(sText, CharNum, 1))
      If CharCode >= 65 And CharCode <= 90 Then
         FixedText = FixedText & " " & Mid(sText, CharNum, 1) 'This needs to be rewritten
      Else
         FixedText = FixedText & Mid(sText, CharNum, 1)
      End If
   Next CharNum

   Add_Spaces = FixedText
End Function
```

Do you have any idea on how i can solve this?

Here is a solution for regex that might give a lead: [R separate words from numbers in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856172/r-separate-words-from-numbers-in-strin)

Comment: Ah, this gets especially fun when there are numbers in the street name like *main 42nd street* :)

Comment: ^^ Even the use of `Ä` accentuated capital characters can prove to be troublesome to some of the answer below (depending on their placement) =)

Comment: Can you explain why not add space after 5 and 19 as `5 :ETVÄRG. 19 .E`. Are there any other exceptions like ` : ` or not?

Comment: Can you also explain why you did NOT add a space after the `TH` in your example #3 `4THFLOOR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function would also work on all examples. It also avoid splitting in case of 'TH' following the number:

```
Private Function SeparateNumbersFromString(x As String) As String
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, strInt As String, strFin As String

   For i = 1 To Len(x)
        strInt = ""
        If IsNumeric(Mid(x, i, 1)) Then
            For j = i To Len(x)
                strInt = strInt & Mid(x, j, 1)
                If Not IsNumeric(strInt) Or (Right(strInt, 1) = "-" And _
                            IsNumeric(left(strInt, Len(strInt) - 1))) Or _
                            (Right(strInt, 1) = "." And _
                               IsNumeric(left(strInt, Len(strInt) - 1))) Then
                    strFin = IIf(strFin = "", strFin, strFin & " ") & _
                                  left(strInt, Len(strInt) - 1) & _
                                   IIf(UCase(Mid(x, j, 2)) = "TH", "", " ")
                    strInt = ""
                    i = j - 1
                    Exit For
                End If
                If j >= Len(x) Then strFin = strFin & " " & strInt: GoTo Ending
            Next j
        Else
            strFin = strFin & Mid(x, i, 1)
        End If
   Next i
Ending:
   SeparateNumbersFromString = strFin
End Function
```

Comment: This solved my problem! I added some formulas in the excel to remove extra spaces generated in data that starts with a number and to remove spaces created before and after -. `=SUBSTITUTE(CLEAN(TRIM(PROPER(SeparateNumbersFromString(DATA))));" - ";"-")`

Comment: @Åsa: Glad I could help you! I started coding of the above function, but I had to leave my office. When I came back I already found three answers and I didn't know if posting another one will help somebody. But, since it was almost ready...

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work on all of your examples:

The regular expression splits on the change from number to letter and vice versa, and also makes an exception for `TH` and `.`

Those exceptions may lead to problems in other data, but seems to work for what you present.  Whether your variability is such that this will be an issue is unknown.

Note that I used early-binding for the Regex (tools/references set to include Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5), but you can change this to late-binding if you will be distributing this code.

**Edit:** *Note that I did NOT convert this to proper case, but that could be done if really required*

```
`Set Reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Option Explicit
Function replacer(s As String) As String
    Dim RE As RegExp
    Const sPat As String = "(\dTH|\d)(?!TH)(?=[A-Z])|([A-Z.])(?=\d)"
    Const sRepl As String = "$1$2 "
    Dim sTemp As String
Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    .IgnoreCase = True
    replacer = .Replace(s, sRepl)
End With

End Function
```

Formula would be, eg:

```
A2: =replacer(A2)
```

If `PROPER` case is required, then change formula to:

```
A2: =PROPER(replacer(A2))
```

*this seems to work better on your data, here in the USA, than does the VBA `StrConv` function.*

[image]

Comment: It's going to be tough to come up with a watertight regex. What if you had a streetname like `25THEODORESTREET4`. Or `5:ETVÄRGÄ19.E`. You rightfully mentioned it worked on the data provided, but something tells me this could cut a bit short. Nice effort nonetheless =)

Comment: @JvdV No question about that. But this may be good enough to winnow the list down to something where manual intervention can finish it off.

Comment: `A-ZÀ-Ý` might improve it slightly.

Comment: @CLR I agree.  But I'll wait for feedback from the OP to see if what we have is good enough.  There may be other tweaks that should also be made.  And I see the OP has accepted the answer that does not separate `TH` from the following if the following starts with a Letter.  Although that is what he showed he wanted in his example.

Answer (score 2):

Try using two regex replacements on the following patterns:

```
([A-Za-z])([0-9])
([0-9])([A-Za-z])
```

and replace with `$1 $2`:

```
Dim Regex As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
Dim input As String = "16AVCHARLESDAGAULLECS10525"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, "([A-Za-z])([0-9])", "$1 $2")
output = Regex.Replace(output, "([0-9])([A-Za-z])", "$1 $2")
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

This prints:

```
16 AVCHARLESDAGAULLECS 10525
```

The strategy here is to match every two boundary characters, in separate capture groups.  A boundary here is a number followed by a letter, or vice-versa.  Then, we replace with those two captured characters, with a space intercolated in between them.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Too late, I already fixed it another way, but your suggestion might be the best.

Comment: @Ron No, hyphenated street names appear to be treated as a single word.

Answer (score 2):

Undoubtedly, Regex is a much tidier way of doing it - but if you wanted to alter your existing code to achieve the desired result I think this might work:

```
Function Add_Spaces(ByVal sText As String) As String
    Dim CharNum As Long
    Dim FixedText As String
    Dim CharCode As Long
    Dim lastCharCode As Long

    FixedText = Left(sText, 1)

    For CharNum = 2 To Len(sText)
        CharCode = Asc(Mid(sText, CharNum, 1))
        lastCharCode = Asc(Mid(sText, CharNum - 1, 1))
         If (CharCode >= 65) <> (lastCharCode >= 65) Then
            FixedText = FixedText & " " & Mid(sText, CharNum, 1) 'This needs to be rewritten
        Else
            FixedText = FixedText & Mid(sText, CharNum, 1)
        End If
    Next CharNum

    Add_Spaces = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(FixedText)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Public Function OutString(Instring As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, CH As String

    L = Len(Instring)
    OutString = Left(Instring, 1)

    For i = 2 To L
        CH = Mid(Instring, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" And Not Right(OutString, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
            OutString = OutString & " " & CH
        Else
            OutString = OutString & CH
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

The code is similar to crawling along the string with a pointer.  If the character to the right of the pointer is a numeral and the character to the left of the pointer is not a numeral, then insert a space.